# How to check tree nodes recursive?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that checkes property `visible` on the one level:

```
   nodeHasAllChildren(node: TreeNode) {
        return node?.children && node?.children.every((child) => child?.visible === false);
    }
```

How to make this recursive to check all nedted nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already have a natural stopping case for your recursion... i.e. if a node has no children, so wouldn't it be as simple as:

```
function nodeHasAllChildren(node: TreeNode): boolean {
    return !!node?.children &&
        node?.children.every((child) => child?.visible === false && 
                                        nodeHasAllChildren(child));
}
```

?